# Funcionamiento de las variables tipo const

Tags: c++

A ver si alguien me puede indicar, que estoy entendiendo mal, a la hora de entender el concepto `const`.

Tengo un atributo de mi clase definida de la siguiente manera:

```
std::string name=""; //Inicialiazado \0.
```

Mi constructor tiene el siguiente aspecto:

```
 Author::Author(const std::string & nam,const std::string  * email, char gender){

      name=nam;
      Author::setEmail_2(email);
      if(Author::checkGender(gender)){
          this->gender=gender;
      }else{
          this->gender='u';
      }
 }
```

No explico todo las funciones de su interior, ya que mi duda se centra en el atributo `name`. Tal y como esta definido el constructor, me tiene que pasar una referencia a un objeto de tipo `string`, y que dicho objeto no puede ser manipulado al ser marcado con `const`.

No entiendo porque me compila, si en principio `nam` (parametro del constructor) es de tipo const `str::string`, no tendría que definir mi atributo como `const` también(ya que al asingar `name=nam`, le estoy pasando a `name` la direccion de `nam`) porque si no lo defino `const`, podría manipular el objeto pasado por parametro, cosa que de entrada no quería, por eso puse que el parametro fuera `const`. No se porque me funciona yo habría puesto el atributo `const`.

Answer (score 2):

> No entiendo porque me compila, si en principio nam (parametro del constructor) es de tipo const str::string, no tendría que definir mi atributo como const también(ya que al asingar name=nam, le estoy pasando a name la direccion de nam)

Te equivocas.

`name` es un miembro de tipo `std::string`, luego cuando llamas al operador de asignación se hace una copia del objeto referenciado por `nam`.

Fíjate en lo que sería la declaración típica del operador de asignación:

```
std::string& operator=(std::string const&);
```

Es decir, recibe **una referencia constante**, que es justamente lo que tu le estás pasando... e internamente copiará el estado del objeto apuntado por dicha referencia. Después de realizar la asignación, el estado de `name` será independiente del estado de `nam` y los cambios que realices en una de estas variables no afectará a la otra... son dos objetos independientes.

Otra cosa es que `name` fuese una referencia (como es el caso de tu otra pregunta):

```
std::string & name;
```

En este caso no se estaría invocando el operador de asignación de la clase `std::string` sino que el programa intentará que `name` referencie al mismo objeto que `nam`... y aquí sí que empezarán los problemas porque `nam` es una referencia constante y `name` no:

```
std::string cadena;

std::string& cad1 = cadena;       // OK, cad1 referencia a cadena
std::string const& cad2 = cadena; // OK, cad2 referencia a cadena (pero no puede modificarla)
std::string& cad3 = cad1;         // OK, cad3 referencia a cadena
std::string const& cad4 = cad1;   // OK
std::string & cad5 = cad2;        // ERROR: cad2 es referencia constante
std::string const& cad6 = cad2;   // OK, cad6 referencia a cadena

cad1 = "hola";
std::cout << cadena << '\n';      // imprime hola
std::cout << cad2 << '\n';        // imprime hola
cad2 = "adios";                   // ERROR: cad2 es una referencia constante
```

Answer (score 1):

> No entiendo porque me compila, si en principio `nam` (parametro del constructor) es de tipo const `str::string`, ¿no tendría que definir mi atributo como `const` también?

Te voy a contar un secreto ¡pero no se lo digas a nadie!: "*En ocasiones veo muertos*".

Ahora conoces mi secreto, ahora somos dos personas las que conocemos mi secreto, no puedes cambiar mi secreto (aunque digas que en ocasiones veo tardígrados, no cambiará el hecho de que yo vea muertos) ahora que lo sabes podrías hacer con esa información lo que te de la gana.

Trasladando a C++ esta historia, mi secreto es `const` (no puedes cambiar algo que yo he vivido) pero aunque tu no puedas cambiar mi vivencia, sí que puedes escribirla en una libreta (la libreta no es `const`), y eso es lo que precisamente está pasando:

```
void f(const std::string &secreto) {
    // Copiamos el secreto
    std::string libreta = secreto;
    // Lo modificamos
    libreta = "No te creo, mientes";
    // Pero como no te creo, ¡cambiaré tu secreto!
    secreto = "En ocasiones veo tardígrados"; // <-- Error de compilación, 'secreto' es const
}

int main() {
    const std::string texto = "En ocasiones veo muertos";
    f(texto);
    return 0;
}
```

---

En otras palabras, los objetos constantes son de sólo lectura; la característica de sólo lectura no se contagia a su alrededor, sólo nos indica que no se podrá modificar el objeto constante.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando asignas nam a mame, la clase string tiene sobrecargado el operador de asignación y en ese caso hace una copia de nam en name, asi que si modificas name no modificarsas nam.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/